# i'm following the Udacity flutter tutorial . It keeps giving me an error saying The named parameter 'child' isn't defined

Tags: flutter

i'm following the Udacity flutter tutorial but it might be a bit outdated . It keeps giving me an error saying The named parameter 'child' isn't defined[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/prXah.png)

Answer (score 2):

The `MaterialApp` widget does not have the parameter `child` anymore. It now uses `home`. Try replacing child with home.

[Here](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/material/MaterialApp-class.html) are all available parameters for `MaterialApp`

Comment: His code is most likely a typo considering the content.

Comment: Could be one. At least now he can accept what applies to him.

Comment: thank you the udacity tutorial is totally outdated. it also does put the new in the tutorial either

Answer (score 1):

Replace `MaterialApp` with `Material`.